# Redirecting HTTP traffic from a subdomain through an SSH tunnel

Tags: networking, ssh, proxy, firewall

I have a machine behind a firewall that I would like to be accessible from the web.
I have a VPS at `example.com`, and I would like traffic sent to `device.example.com` to reach my device behind the firewall.

I've managed to get the firewalled device accessible through `example.com:2210` with the use of a reverse SSH tunnel. On the firewalled device, I ran `ssh -R 2210:localhost:22 root@example.com`.

Now, I would like HTTP traffic sent to `device.example.com` to be redirected to my firewalled device. I looked at using a SOCKS proxy, but nginx on `example.com` seems to be too high of a network layer for a SOCKS proxy.
How can I redirect all HTTP traffic (or even all network traffic) to my firewalled device?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you need to look at the `Host` header in HTTP requests (unless you have multiple IP addresses, so `subdomain.example.com` can have a dedicated address), you need something that deals with HTTP. So nginx is definitely a good choice. You need to set it up as a so-called “reverse proxy”.

When the reverse proxy receives a request, it will be forwarded (internally) to the specified “upstream” service. The service’s response will then be returned to the client. The client doesn’t know anything about this.

Setting up a reverse proxy is super easy on both [Apache](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/reverse_proxy.html) and [nginx](https://www.nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/reverse-proxy/).

Comment: What if I wanted to receive more than HTTP traffic? e.g. run an arbitrary service on port xxxx and be able to access it through `device.example.com:xxxx`

Comment: Few protocols have a concept of host names. So your service will also be available at `example.com`, because you’re probably using wildcard subdomains that all point to a single IP address. You could just open up your SSH reverse tunnel publicly. // Keep in mind though that the original remote address is lost this way. A more complicated setup with a VPN tunnel and port forwarding is probably better, but requires good network knowledge.